# setImageURI(url) is deprecated in Fresco. What to use instead?

Tags: android, image, kotlin, deprecated, fresco

I am using Fresco Android Library to get images from URLs. The images I get without any problem, but the thing is that the `setImageURI(url)` is deprecated.[image]
So I could not find what to use instead. To avoid deprecated functions usage in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use this method: `setImageURI(String uriPath)`

```
val uriPath = arrayList!![position].getUrl()
draweeView.setImageURI(uriPath)
```

Comment: It's not the same. In your method, that's taking URI as a parameter but here I am using another method that takes String as a parameter.

Comment: There are 4 overrides, are they all deprecated?

Comment: Thank you. Now it doesn't show that it is deprecated.

Comment: @ArmenHovhannisian Cool :)

Comment: However, if you are converting from Uri -> String just for the method call, you're doing unnecessary work since it's internally converted back to Uri.

https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/drawee/src/main/java/com/facebook/drawee/view/SimpleDraweeView.java#L155  See my comment below for alternatives.

Comment: so what to do ? Alexander Oprisnik

Comment: See my answer below, use `setImageUri(uri, callerContext)`

Answer (score 5):

`SimpleDraweeView#setImageURI(Uri)` is actually `@undeprecate`d (https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/drawee/src/main/java/com/facebook/drawee/view/SimpleDraweeView.java#L117) but this command is not a standard JavaDoc command and there is no better way to undeprecate something that has been marked as deprecated in a parent class.

However, you should use `SimpleDraweeView#setImageURI(Uri uri, @Nullable Object callerContext)` instead. The caller context can be null or it can be additional metadata (like a String TAG that can be used to better identify where image requests are coming from).